# Coconuts problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve the following problem and I would appreciate any help on where I am wrong

**Problem**

> Five men crash-land their airplane on a deserted island in the South
>   Pacific. On their first day they gather as many coconuts as they can
>   find into one big pile. They decide that, since it is getting dark,
>   they will wait until the next day to divide the coconuts.
>
> That night each man took a turn watching for rescue searchers while
>   the others slept. The first watcher got bored so he decided to divide
>   the coconuts into five equal piles. When he did this, he found he had
>   one remaining coconut. He gave this coconut to a monkey, took one of
>   the piles, and hid it for himself. Then he jumbled up the four other
>   piles into one big pile again.
>
> To cut a long story short, each of the five men ended up doing exactly
>   the same thing. They each divided the coconuts into five equal piles
>   and had one extra coconut left over, which they gave to the monkey.
>   They each took one of the five piles and hid those coconuts. They each
>   came back and jumbled up the remaining four piles into one big pile.
>
> What is the smallest number of coconuts there could have been in the
>   original pile?

**My approach**

I let $o$ be the original number of coconuts

We know that when $o$ is divided into 5 piles there is one left, so we can say that
$o=5a+1$ where $a$ represents the number of coconuts in the equal piles that were split.

I then know that the 4 piles saved where again split equally and there was one left so writing an equation for each of the 5 splits we have the following
$$o=5a+1$$
$$4a=5b+1$$
$$4b=5c+1$$
$$4c=5d+1$$
$$4d=5e+1$$

So I begin substituting back to the original
$$\begin{align} 
o&=\frac{5}{4}(5b+1) \\
o&=\frac{5^2}{4}b+\frac{5}{4} \\
o&=\frac{5^3}{4^2}c+\frac{5^2}{4^2}+\frac{5}{4} \\
o&=\frac{5^4}{4^3}d+\frac{5^3}{4^3}+\frac{5^2}{4^2}+\frac{5}{4} \\
o&=\frac{5^5}{4^4}e+\frac{5^4}{4^4}+\frac{5^3}{4^3}+\frac{5^2}{4^2}+\frac{5}{4}
\end{align}$$

Now at this point I try to see if im on the right way and I check the solution which is somehow
$$ o = (\frac{5^5}{4^4}) (e + 1) − 4$$

By substituting a value for e I know my equation and this is not equal, so what did I do wrong and how did it get here?

Comment: I think the usual approach is to add four blue coconuts ...

Comment: You will find [this article](http://wordplay.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/10/07/gardner-2/?_php=true&_type=blogs&_r=0) interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot one in the first step:
$$\begin{align}o&=5a+1\\
&=\frac54(5b+1)+1\\
&=\frac{5^2}4b+\frac54+1.\end{align} $$
Finally note that $1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4=\frac{a^5-1}{a-1}$ to simplify the sum of powers in the end (or, use four blue coconuts).

Comment: Oh, Thanks! Okay I added the +1 and now the two solutions are equal but can you please explain more thoroughly how can I "simplify the sum of powers", because there is a variable e in there and I don't know what to do with it